# Excel VBA Type Mismatch for #N/A

Tags: vba, excel

I have this chunk of code

```
    With Data.Cells(rowMatch, GWECol)
        .Value = Cmp.Cells(i, GWENetPr)
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Text Text:=UCase(Environ("UserName")) & ":" & vbNewLine _
            & "Comment: " & Cmp.Cells(i, CommCol) & vbNewLine _
            & "Transaction: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRTran) & vbNewLine _
            & "QR Pr: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRPr) & vbNewLine _
            & "QR WD: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRWD) & vbNewLine _
            & "QR WD All: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRWDA) & vbNewLine _
            & "QR XPr: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRXPr) & vbNewLine _
            & "QR XAll: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRXAll) & vbNewLine _
            & "GWE Pr: " & Cmp.Cells(i, GWEPr) & vbNewLine _
            & "GWE All: " & Cmp.Cells(i, GWEAll) & vbNewLine _
            & "GWE XPr: " & Cmp.Cells(i, GWEXPr) & vbNewLine _
            & "GWE XAll: " & Cmp.Cells(i, GWEXAll)
        .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    End With
```

Where the Cmp.Cells(i, X) refers to cells that may have #N/A error (a failed VLOOKUP).

Is it possible to have the code just take in the #N/A as a string or just leave it empty? Right now, whenever one of the cells referenced is #N/A, the chunk will fail and no comment text will be added at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all!! I actually did something similar to Sorceri's solution right after posting this. But will be editing it to the `.Text` property instead. Was not aware of that property. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the default property of the cell,

`Debug.Print Cmp.Cells(i, QRXAll)`

For example this always refers to the cells `.Value` property.  The `.Value` is actually an error type, `Error 2042` which I think you could avoid by checking

`CLng(Cmp.Cells(i,QRXA11))`

But this will result in `2042` instead of the `#N/A` text.

If you want to get the string `#N/A`: try using `Cmp.Cells(i, QRXAll).Text`  which relies on the cell's `.Text` property instead of its `.Value`.

`Debug.Print Cmp.Cells(i, QRXAll).Text`

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have done some VBA programming, but I wouldn't call myself an expert.

This may be overly simplistic, but you could just assign each value to a variable and then assign the variables to the comment. If any one value is N/A, at least the rest of your values will still be assigned to the comment. I perfer this kind of solution as it ensures that a single error will not derail the entire operation.

```
Dim vComment As String
Dim vTransaction As String
Dim vQRPr As String
Dim vQRWD As String
' Etc.

vComment = Cmp.Cells(i, CommCol).Text
vTransaction = Cmp.Cells(i, QRTran).Text
vQRPr = Cmp.Cells(i, QRPr).Text
vQRWD = Cmp.Cells(i, QRWD).Text
' Etc.

.Comment.Text Text:=UCase(Environ("UserName")) & ":" & vbNewLine _
        & "Comment: " & vComment & vbNewLine _
        & "Transaction: " & vTransaction & vbNewLine _
        & "QR Pr: " & vQRPr & vbNewLine _
        & "QR WD: " & vQRWD & vbNewLine
        ' Etc.
```

*Edited: Thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924948/excel-vba-type-mismatch-for-n-a/18925052?noredirect=1#comment27942280_18925052) for pointing out that the `.Text` property should be used*

Comment: Can't be implemented this way because the cell's `.Value` property is an error type, and won't cast in to a string container. YOu'd have to dimension the variables as `Variant` but that will return a string like `Error 2042` instead of the cell's text contents, which can be obtained from its `.Text` property.

Comment: @DavidZemens - Working mostly from .NET interop, I suspected something more like your solution but wasn't sure exactly how to implement it in VBA. I'll update the answer with `.Text`

Comment: My answer already solves the problem, no use duplicating it :)

Comment: @DavidZemens - I think it's still good practice to divide the values into variables rather than trying to perform so many functions in a single statement. It ensures that a single error won't derail the entire operation. (I have already upvoted your answer...)

Comment: I also prefer working with variables directly. Easier to debug and maintain in the future.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is good practice to separate variables with the functions. I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1):

use IsError to check to see if the cells has #N/A

```
 if IsError(Cmp.Cells(i, GWENetPr)) then
      'give it a valid value
else
      'use the value int he cell
end if

'start with statement
```

example

```
With Data.Cells(rowMatch, GWECol)
    If IsError(Cmp.Cells(i, GWENetPr)) Then
        .Value = "" 'or #N/A
    Else
        .Value = Cmp.Cells(i, GWENetPr)
    End If

    .AddComment
    .Comment.Text Text:=UCase(Environ("UserName")) & ":" & vbNewLine _
        & "Comment: " & Cmp.Cells(i, CommCol) & vbNewLine _
        & "Transaction: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRTran) & vbNewLine _
        & "QR Pr: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRPr) & vbNewLine _
        & "QR WD: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRWD) & vbNewLine _
        & "QR WD All: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRWDA) & vbNewLine _
        & "QR XPr: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRXPr) & vbNewLine _
        & "QR XAll: " & Cmp.Cells(i, QRXAll) & vbNewLine _
        & "GWE Pr: " & Cmp.Cells(i, GWEPr) & vbNewLine _
        & "GWE All: " & Cmp.Cells(i, GWEAll) & vbNewLine _
        & "GWE XPr: " & Cmp.Cells(i, GWEXPr) & vbNewLine _
        & "GWE XAll: " & Cmp.Cells(i, GWEXAll)
    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
End With
```

Comment: Why not just use the appropriate property? Instead of using the object's default property ( `.Value`),  specify the `.Text` property?  Otherwise, you have to wrap every cell range object in an `IIF` statement with `IsError` handling...

Comment: It is a matter of preference at this point. Returning true or false is easier then getting the text and then checking to see if that text value is NA and is easier to read and understand.

Comment: The OP specifically wants the `#N/A` text. if you use the `.Text` property instead of `.Value`, that's what will be returned instead of the error-type. There's no need to perform any boolean evaluation on this, I don't think.

Comment: the OP wants it blank or #N/A.  provided the example above.  Really it is a matter of preference.  The code I show is very easy to read and understand.

Comment: Presumably you need to do that 11 more times, for each range object `Cmp.Cells(i,...)`, then it works. But it's messy, IMO. Also, OP doesn't indicate that he wants to overwrite the cell's `.Value` - he wants the VBA to take either the string `#N/A` (obtained from the `.Text` property, or a blank value, which would require logic like yours, repeated for each cell object :)

Comment: no we don’t, we don’t have enough information for the other cells to make that judgment so that is a very erroneous statement. OP posted 'Where the Cmp.Cells(i, X) refers to cells that may have #N/A error (a failed VLOOKUP)'.

Comment: My point is - there are a dozen references to a cell that meets the criteria `Cmp.Cells(i,`X`)`.  Assuming OP used "X" to indicate it could be in any of those 12 references(i.e., "whenever one of those cells...").  Perhaps too much of a presumption on my part, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: What would help is if the OP clarified if that is the case or if it is just the one cell.

Comment: Apologies, as I definitely did not phrase my question in the best way. Yes, the X refers to any of the cell that may have the error. It may be just one, but more likely than not would be multiple of them. I actually had all those variables up there with the multiple `If` statements. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IIf` to use a specific value if there is an error:

```
& "Comment: " & IIf(IsError(Cmp.Cells(i, CommCol)),"",Cmp.Cells(i, CommCol)) & vbNewLine _
```

Comment: I think you meant to use backticks... ;)