# Multiligual representation of #N/A in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a program in Excel VBA and I'm trying to filter for #N/A. This is a string, so it becomes "#N/A".

I'm using the English version.

My client is in The Netherlands and uses the Dutch version. "#N/A" doesn't work for him. According to the documentation, this is "#N/B"

There should be a way to obtain this in Dutch

- `xlErrNA` returns 2042
- `CVErr(xlErrNA)` returns Error 2042
- `Error(xlErrNA)` returns "Application defined or object defined error"
- `Err.Raise(xlErrNA)` returns "Application defined or object defined error"
- `NA()` ... doesn't exist in VBA
- `WorksheetFunction.NA()` ... doesn't exist either

Comment: kind of a dirty solution, but how just filter on `#N` or just `#`. This of course assumes that there would be no other data in the list with these values. Also, by filter, I assume you are using the `.AutoFilter` method within your VBA.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman How would you do that?

Comment: First, just to be clear, are you trying to filter on a column of data for all the #N/A (#N/B)? I want to make sure I know what you are doing before I lead you down a path! :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I just added some code below. This works.

Comment: Awesome. Looks like you can mark your own answer as the one :)

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually find a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18925047/11498) on StackOverflow.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=NA()"
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text
```

If anybody finds a better (direct) method, I'd love to hear it.

```
Dim rng As Range
'On the assumption that nobody reaches x+100 years old
'Current age x is usually >50
'In the Table, Age is the third field
Set rng = Range("TableAOW[Age]").Range("A100")
If IsError(rng) Then
    Range("TableAOW").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & rng.Text, Operator:=xlAnd
End If
```

Comment: In VBA you can also try `WorksheetFunction.IsError` or `WorksheetFunction.IsNA`

Comment: @paulbica, these functions return True or False, not a string